# C# Core, aspnetCore api, Llave secreta de mi sistema no la lee cuando publico en IIS local

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis, variables-globales, publish

disculpen si no me expreso bien es mi primer pregunta en stackoverflow, cree una api con C# Core, estas son las versiones tal cuales según mi archivo de proyecto:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.12">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.21" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

dicho proyecto manejo la autentificación por medio de JWT, tengo todo configurado y correcto, para el cifrado Hago que lea una variable global de nombre #Secret# la cual guarde en el proyecto. tanto para la creación de mi token como el desencriptado del mismo.

Creación:

```
private IActionResult BuildToken(UserInfo userInfo)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, userInfo.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,userInfo.Rol)
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Secret"]));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

    JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
       issuer: "www.example.com",
       audience: "www.example.com",
       claims,
       expires: expiration,
       signingCredentials: creds);

    return Ok(new
    {
        token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
        expiration = expiration,
        email = userInfo.Email
    });

}
```

Desencriptado:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuer = false,
             ValidateAudience = false,
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
             Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Secret"])),
             ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
         });
```

todo el proyecto me funciona excelente cuando lo ejecuto desde visual studio, el problema esta al realizar la publicación a mi IIS local o en mi servidor de gcloud, cuando quiero generar el token me aparece un error del parámetro no puede ser Null y solamente es en IIS local y GCloud

```
{
    "ClassName": "System.ArgumentNullException",
    "Message": "String reference not set to an instance of a String.",
}
```

al parecer ese error me da porque no puede leer la llave #Secret# y no se como hacer para que esa variable global al momento de la publicación en IIS como en Gcloud me la lea... alguien puede darme como hacer que esa variable global sea leída, les agradecería mucho,

Saludos y espero puedan ayudarme gracias.

Comment: en dónde está tu `secret`? si está en appsettings.json, verifica que no sea en el entorno de desarrollo

Comment: Secret lo tengo en las propiedades del proyecto, pestaña depurar, como variable global

Comment: Variable de entorno, es el nombre

Comment: En casos así, desde Visual Studio, remote debugging y a revisar lo que ocurre en el servidor :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al ponerme a investigar sobre las variables de entorno, descubrí que existen 2 archivos de configuración `appSetting.json` y `launchSettings.json` mi variable `Secret` la tenia como variable de entorno en `launchSettings.json` y al realizar la publicación a mi IIS local o en mi Gcloud no me asignaba ese valor en el diccionario de `Configuration` eso asumo que es por que no he configurado mi entorno de `launchSettings.json`

lo solucione pasando mi variable `Secret` en `appSetting.json`, pero siento que todavía es una debilidad en seguridad.

Comment: Dudo mucho que sea un error de seguridad, el error era de configuración. De seguridad sería si tienes ese archivo de libre acceso, cosa que no creo, ¿verdad?

Comment: no, es un archivo que tengo protegido con permisos de acceso, aunque soy nuevo en eso de publicar en `Gcloud` voy aprendiendo